# jQuery Select By Content Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, jquery-selectors

I need to select all paragraphs < p > within a < div > that have a pattern matching time stamps formatting like:

```
<p>[22:48]</p>
```

or

```
<p>[22:48 - Subject Line]</p>
```

How can this be done with jQuery?

**UPDATE**

Valid formats for times:

```
1:24
24:59
1:24:01
```

Invalid formats for times:

```
24:70 [70 is not possible]
56:123 [last segment must have 2 digits from 00 - 59]
```

Comment: What about `<p> aa [22:48]</p>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div p').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().match(/\[\d{2}:\d{2}.*\]/);
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nmhL5/)

**Update:**

use this `regex`:

```
/^\[\d*:?[0-6]?[0-9]:[0-6][0-9]\D?.*\]$/
```

Comment: the last segment of the time code must be 2 digits but any others do not have to be

Comment: @phirschybar. Can you show more examples of valid and invalid `<p>` ?

Comment: @phirschybar. I updated. Next time give the options in `<p> ...</p>` format.